# How Read String Value from Registry in c++?

Tags: c++, string, winapi, registry

please some one tell me whats wrong ?
i copy this code and gives me error ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
there is a string value in registry with name of "name"

```
string GetRegistry()
{
    DWORD dwType = REG_SZ;
    HKEY Handler = 0;
    string subkey = "Key123\\";
    string value_name = "name";
    DWORD AnswerType;
    char data[32];
    DWORD buffer_size = 32;
    LSTATUS Answer = RegOpenKeyA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, subkey.c_str(), &Handler);
    if (Answer != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        return "Faild To Open Registry Key";
    }

    Answer=RegGetValueA(Handler, subkey.c_str(), value_name.c_str(), RRF_RT_REG_SZ, &AnswerType, data, &buffer_size);
    RegCloseKey(Handler);
    string return_data = "";
    for (unsigned int a = 0; a < 32; a++) {
        return_data += (char)*(data + a);
    }
    return return_data;
}
```

Comment: Why does the subkey have a trailing backspace?

Comment: What exactly gives you `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`? Which function call? How do you get that value/string? Is it part of the return value of the function `GetRegistry`? Please provide a [mre] and specify the exact input (e.g. registry contents), exact output and desired output.

Comment: RegGetValueA returns ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: @milad: What makes you think that `RegGetValueA` returns that value? Did you print it out? If so, please show us how you are printing it out. Or did you inspect the value of `Answer` in a debugger?

Comment: Looks like you are asking for a value in HKCU\Key123\Key123\ but mean to ask for a value in HKCU\Key123\ because the subkey in the call to `RegGetValueA` is relative to the key returned by `RegOpenKeyA`. One conclusion is that you can just call `RegGetValueA` passing `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` as the handle and avoid calling `RegOpenKeyA` at all. The rest of the code is littered with issues. Why copy this code? Surely time would be better spent learning how to do this properly?

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing `RegGetValueA()`.

Its `lpValue` parameter is relative to its `lpSubKey` parameter, which is relative to its `hkey` parameter.

You are using `RegOpenKeyA()` (which is deprecated, you should be using `RegOpenKeyExA()` instead) to open the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Key123` key, and then you are calling `RegGetValuA()` with its `hKey` parameter set to that open key, its `lpSubKey` parameter set to `"Key123"`, and its `lpValue` parameter set to `"name"`.

So, you are asking `RegGetValueA()` to read the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Key123\Key123\name` value, but you meant to read the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Key123\name` value instead.  That is why `RegGetValueA()` is failing with `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

So, you need to either:

- use `RegOpenKeyExA()` to open `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Key123`, and then use `RegQueryValueEx()` (or `RegGetValueA()` with `lpSubKey=NULL`) to read the `name` value in that open key, eg:

  ```
  string GetRegistry()
  {
      HKEY Handler = NULL;
      string subkey = "Key123";
      string value_name = "name";
      char data[32];
      DWORD buffer_size = 32;

      LSTATUS Answer = RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, subkey.c_str(), 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &Handler);
      if (Answer != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
          return "Failed To Open Registry Key";
      }

      Answer = RegQueryValueExA(Handler, value_name.c_str(), NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)data, &buffer_size);
      RegCloseKey(Handler);

      if (Answer != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
          return "Failed To Read Registry Value";
      }

      // the data MAY or MAY NOT be null-terminated,
      // ignore the terminator if it is present...
      if ((buffer_size > 0) && (data[buffer_size-1] == '\0')) {
          --buffer_size;
      }

      return string(data, buffer_size);
  }
  ```

  ```
  string GetRegistry()
  {
      HKEY Handler = NULL;
      string subkey = "Key123";
      string value_name = "name";
      char data[32];
      DWORD buffer_size = 32;

      LSTATUS Answer = RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, subkey.c_str(), 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &Handler);
      if (Answer != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
          return "Failed To Open Registry Key";
      }

      Answer = RegGetValueA(Handler, NULL, value_name.c_str(), RRF_RT_REG_SZ, NULL, data, &buffer_size);
      RegCloseKey(Handler);

      if (Answer != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
          return "Failed To Read Registry Value";
      }

      // the data IS null-terminated, ignore the terminator...
      return string(data, buffer_size-1);
  }
  ```
- use `RegGetValueA()` by itself, do not use `RegOpenKeyExA()` at all, eg:

  ```
  string GetRegistry()
  {
      HKEY Handler = NULL;
      string subkey = "Key123";
      string value_name = "name";
      char data[32];
      DWORD buffer_size = 32;

      LSTATUS Answer = RegGetValueA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, subkey.c_str(), value_name.c_str(), RRF_RT_REG_SZ, NULL, data, &buffer_size);
      if (Answer != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
          return "Failed To Read Registry Key Value";
      }

      // the data is null-terminated, ignore the terminator...
      return string(data, buffer_size-1);
  }
  ```